# How to align a layout to left while both left and right constraints are applied to it inside Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

This is the layout I want to design:

[image]

As you can see from the image, I want the linear layout to be constrained to both Item A and Item B and I want it aligned to left. I couldn't find any way to implement this inside a Constraint Layout. When I use this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ui_size_xs">
```

linear layout moves to the middle.
When I use this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ui_size_xs">
```

the linear layout occupies the whole area between Items A and B.
**I want the linear layout to be `wrap-content` but should also align to the left like in the image**. The only solution I could find is to create a new layout as parent of this linear layout and give `0dp` to new parent linear layout and `wrap-conent` to this layout child layout. I don't want to do that. Is there any way to achieve this without creating any extra layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in [offical docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#Bias),

> The default when encountering such opposite constraints is to center the widget; but you can tweak the positioning to favor one side over another using the bias attributes:
>
> - layout_constraintHorizontal_bias
> - layout_constraintVertical_bias

Try the following and see if it works

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ui_size_xs"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="item1id"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeft="item2id">

// try different horizontal bias values to meet your need
```

Comment: putting 0 as the bias will align the view to the left!
putting 1 as the bias will align the view to the right. Right on.